# VMware Openstack Autopilot appliance install failed/unavailable

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Does anybody able to install openstack appliance for vmware? Link on the web page is dead (https://landscape.canonical.com/downloads/vmware-autopilot/vmware-openstack-autopilot.tar.bz2)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the VMware appliance was discontinued. From the [README.txt](https://landscape.canonical.com/downloads/vmware-autopilot/README.txt) file:

> The Autopilot Testdrive on VMware has been discontinued.
>
> Downloads have been moved to an archive directory at
>
> https://landscape.canonical.com/downloads/archive/
>
> August 17th, 2016.